# This is not a duplicate

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, duplicates

I have a question about my Physics Stack Exchange post: [If antiparticles are particles moving back in time, would messages from the future be possible?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/686526/if-antiparticles-are-particles-moving-back-in-time-would-messages-from-the-futu)

It was marked a duplicate of [Is anti-matter going backwards in time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/is-anti-matter-matter-going-backwards-in-time)

At first glance, these questions are obviously not the same. I'm asking if future-to-past/present messages are possible, **if** Feynman's interpretation of antiparticles is true. I'm not asking whether or not it is true, that would ultimately (at least for now) be a philosophical question. Instead, my question asks about whether or not *something else* would be possible, **if** the Feynman interpretation is true.

But just because our questions are different, it doesn't mean that I can't find an answer to my question in those provided to the other one. So, I looked through them. Perhaps I'm too illiterate in physics, but I don't see how the answers to that question answer my question. And don't say "it's obvious that messages could be sent from the future to the past/present if this interpretation is true, as this interpretation, by definition, allows retrocausality". Just because retrocausality is possible, doesn't mean "retrocausal communication" is. It seems obvious that faster-than-light communication is made possible by quantum entanglement, but it isn't. I didn't know that until I was told. So, applying the same principle of ignorance here, I need to be told by those that actually have expertise, whether Feynman's interpretation of anti-particles actually allows for future-to-past/present communication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When asking a controversial question, like, if messages from the future would be possible, it is recommended to tie it to the academic discussion, e.g. mentioning Feynman's interpretation. I edited and reopened the question.

Comment: Thanks. Is the question controversial because of Feynman's interpretation being controversial, or because it's asking about some maybe speculative implications of that interpretation/something else inherent to the question? If the former, I'm a bit surprised. I didn't think Feynman's interpretation was controversial, since as far as I can tell, few physicist believe in it, and thus it may not be sufficiently popular to create enough disagreement to count as controversial. Though, maybe it has sparked a lot of disagreement?